# ZendSession giving fatal error when trying to include

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

I'm getting an error when trying to include Session.php for the Zend Framework.

Here's how I include it:

```
$ZEND_LIBRARY_PATH = "path_to_zend_library_folder";
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $ZEND_LIBRARY_PATH); 
include_once '../classes/zend/library/zend/Session.php';
$account_info = new Zend_Session_Namespace('account');
```

The file gets included ok, but I get this error: `Cannot redeclare class Zend_Session`
How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying include that class second time.. Try to comment `include_once` line and check if it works without it.
Maybe you use autoload already.

Comment: thanks hsz, but I get this error: `"Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Session_Namespace' not found"` I haven't installed the framework with a bootstrap, I just include the classes as I need, and don't use the auto loader.  Currently the only zend classes I use are currency and date classes. any other ideas?

Comment: Try to include `../classes/zend/library/zend/Session/Namespace.php`

Comment: Still another fatal error: `"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Session_Namespace"`

Comment: With that last warning you had only one (`...../Session/Namespace.php`) include in your code ?